# How to approximate a normal distribution?

Tags: time-series, probability, distributions, descriptive-statistics

I want to reduce the space requirement of a probability distribution.

I have a main factory with a psychic alarm/monitor that can predict accidents.
It pings once per second with continuous variables of peak volume, pitch, and timbre (v, p, t).

I don't have access to the alarm, but every time there is an accident, a worker records the N preceding steps or outputs of the alarm. I get a report at the end of the month with a set of observations, each one being the N steps before an accident. Let's say 5 observations of 2 adjacent steps, for 5 total accidents.

I describe the set of 2 step sequences as the 'accident-distribution' - a multivariate probability distribution of 6 variables,
(x1=v1, x2=p1, x3=t1, x4=v2, x5=p2, x6=t2) with normally distributed values, so that's a mean vector of length 6, and a 6x6 covariance matrix.

I send the accident distribution to my other factories.
When they think there could be an accident soon, they take a sample recording of 2 steps of their own separate monitors. It's a strict requirement / limitation that they must estimate the probability of a near-term accident from only a single reference sample.
They estimate the probability that an accident is about to occur by using the cdf or integration of the pdf, referencing the accident-distribution.
If high probability, they change what they're doing to avoid an accident.
This example is made up, but hopefully it conveys the situation.

**My question is, are there alternative ways to represent the accident-distribution**, such that my employees can still calculate what they need to?
The problem we're having is that we increase N to get more preceding timesteps of an accident for better quality, but as N increases, **the size of the covariance matrix increases quadratically**.
Is there a way to save space, or a form to approximate the cov-matrix or distribution? It's probably irregular to treat a timeseries of 2 steps like I do as 6 variable multivariate, but I don't know an alternative.

**EDIT: a simplified description:**

There's a world where states occur at even intervals. The states are partial observations of the full world. A fixed-parameterized model outputs X, representing a set of hypothetical length N sequences of adjacent states. Then I have a real observed sequence of N states, and I want to say what is the probability that these are in X (the hypothetical set)?

Is there a representation of X, the output set, that doesn't scale quadratically with N (ie. outputting a distribution by mean vector and covariance matrix, which is quadratic), of which I can estimate the probability of an observation? A hidden markov model has been suggested.

Comment: It sounds like what you're describing is a nearest-neighbor like approach, where "nearness" is assessed as the distance between two vectors of alarm observations. You can give each component a different weight; in general you would have a full covariance matrix. Computing distance as x . A . x where A is an arbitrary positive definite matrix is the so-called Mahalanobis distance. Anyway it's common to let A be diagonal, or even just the identity matrix, i.e. all components get the same weight.

Comment: If you're actually work with time series, there is probably a sweet spot of vector length; too short and too long give less accurate results, and you can only judge the right size empirically, i.e. try different sizes and see what works best. By the way, if it's at all possible, you can help others help you by talking about the actual problem instead of contrived example. Hope this helps.

Comment: I know of Mahalanobis distance, and I could use that. I don't understand the rest of your comment. Are you saying instead of using the actual full covariance matrix, I could just use the identity matrix? That seems like it would be terribly detrimental to the assessment of predicting the probably that a sample is from the distribution.

Comment: Well, whether or not the successive variables are approximately independent or not is indeed a strong modeling assumption, but it's also very common in problems related to time series -- the most common model is something like y(k) = f(x(k)) + epsilon(k) where epsilon(k) is independent of epsilon(j) when j != k. More complex models, e.g. autoregressive, assume those terms are dependent, but, as you point out, that makes the analysis more complex.

Comment: Whether or not that complexity is justified depends entirely on what you're working with and what goal you want to reach, so, again, it would help others giving advice to you if you say more about the specifics of the problem. My advice at this point is to reformulate your question with that in mind and post that as a new question, and maybe delete this one to focus attention on the new one.

Comment: @RobertDodier They are definitely dependent, analogous to the interdependence of individual words in a sentence. If I do create a new post, I would just use the 'simplified description' that I added to the bottom of the current post. Is there anything you see it lacks?

Comment: Re: dependence, yes, that's important to know. About creating a new post, I pretty strong advise describing the actual problem.

Comment: It's typically more helpful if you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve than a pseudo problem you believe is close.